# Toggling class causes inner html of element to disappear

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having trouble toggling a class on an element in my component. From the inspector, I can see that the class successfully toggles. However, when the `#navbarToggle` is clicked, everything inside of `#navbarMenu` is removed and it becomes an empty list. I can verify this in the inspector as all the list items just disappear.

I have a navbar component with an html page consisting of:

```
<nav>
    <span #navbarToggle>Toggle</span>

    <ul class="hidden" #navbarMenu>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And scss with a simple declaration:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

And in my components ts file:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-navbar',

  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']

})

export class NavbarComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('navbarMenu') navbarMenu: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('navbarToggle') navbarToggle: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.renderer.listen(this.navbarToggle.nativeElement, 'click', () => {

      this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.navbarMenu.nativeElement).classList.toggle('hidden');

    });

  }

}
```

Comment: This is not a very ng-like way to do this; better would be to leverage the inbuilt functionality of ngClass or ngStyle, or even an ngIf...

Comment: @danimal I'm looking those up now, I just picked up angular today and I'm trying to absorb a lot of information. Could you provide an example as an answer?

Comment: I updated my answer with a stackblitz example. Please let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) The problem with having the toggle listener on the `ul` is that if there is only 1 `li` and you toggle it away, there will be nothing of the `ul` left to click.

2) It would be much better to use an Angular built-in structural directive like *ngIf or a class binding.

Here's a stackblitz class binding example (where the trigger is not the `ul`): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8lihrj

---

In the docs, class binding: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding

ngIf: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#syntax